# Grafana for K8S - configure dashboard access permissions

Tags: azure, kubernetes, grafana, persistent-volumes, prometheus-operator

We have configured Grafana `user` and `admin` roles using `Grafana.ini` which works great.

Now we want to provide some permission to user  to
see **specific dashboards**, e.g. user X can see 5 dashboard and user Y can see 8 dashboards according to some configurations (permissions).

We were able to keep this config in Grafana UI but if the pod (K8S) is fail the details is deleted,  we are using latest [prom helm](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts) .

My question is how should we
store this data right, even if the pod is restarted?

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/permissions/dashboard-folder-permissions/

https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts

https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L253

Any solution/direction will be helpful as I believe that grafana store this data someware but not sure where ...

I found this link which is talking about the store of the users on database etc
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#database

Not sure what is missing as the data should be kept in k8s volume...
If there is any other solution or a way to solve it please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy your Grafana instance with a persistent storage. Either:

- Keep using the built-in sqlite db - just ensure to use [PVC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) to store it's data. The default path can be set using this [config property](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#data)
- Use external db, like SQL, and configure Grafana to talk with it. See the [database](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#database) config section for more details.

Grafana persistency will be used to persist other settings as well, and also persist dashboards, alerts etc.
All settings can be set via the `grafana.ini` helm chart variable